# comparison of two first order pde problems $u_x + cu_y =0$ vs. $u_x + cu_y =1$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I am analyzing two similar first order PDE problems.

1) $u_x + cu_y =0 \ \ $ and  $ \ \ u(0,y)= sin(y)$

and

2)  $u_t + cu_x =1 \ \ $ and  $ \ \ u(0,y)= sin(y)$

As I understand 1) The solution is a sinusoidal plane. The curves on the plane x,y defined as $$y=cx + a$$ have the same constant value of u alongside the each curve, therefore value of u depends on the constant $a$ so that $u=sin(-c/a)$

Is my understanding of 1) correct?

How the situation is changed when left hand side of the equation equals one instead of zero? does it mean that the whole plane moves up simply  by one?

Comment: Are the boundary conditions wrong? $u(0,y)=\sin(x)=0$, since $x=0$. Should $x$ be $y$?

Comment: yes, the boundary should be $u(0,y)=\sin(y)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that I alter the boundary conditions of the original questions.

1).$u_x+cu_y=0=(1,c)\cdot(u_x,u_y)$, which implies that $u(x,y)$ is a constant along the characteristic line $y=cx+a$. So, $u(x,y)=f(cx-y)$. We can check that $f(cx-y)$ satisfies the original equation. From the boundary condition, we know $u(0,y)=f(-y)=\sin(y)$. So, $f(x)=-\sin(x)$. $u(x,y)=-\sin(cx-y)$.

2). Follow the same argument, we know $u_x+cu_y=1=(1,c)\cdot(u_x,u_y)$, which implies that $u(x,y)$ is a linear function along the characteristic line $y=cx+a$. So, $u(x,cx+a)=x+b$. Since $u(0,a)=\sin(a)=b$. So, $u(x,cx+a)=x+\sin(a)$. $u(x,y)=x-\sin(cx-y)$.

Comment: could you expound how you deduced the  $f(x)=-\sin(x)$ and $u(x,y)=-\sin(cx-y)$?

Comment: you know $f(-y)=\sin(y)$, so , $f(x)=-\sin(x)$. $u(x,cx+a)=x+sin(a)$. So, $u(x,y)=x-\sin(cx-y)$

Comment: I mean the 1)  what allows to conclude that $f(x)=-\sin(x)$  and then $u(x,y)=-\sin(cx-y)$ I don't get this part

Comment: I see. In 1), since, we know $u(x,y)$ is a constant along the line $y=cx+a$, and know the boundary points $u(0,y)=\sin(y)$. So, when we calculate $u(x,y)$, we move it back to the boundary point along the characteristic line. The corresponding point is $(0,y-cx)$. So, $u(x,y)=u(0,y-cx)=\sin(y-cx)$

Comment: I am still confused why in the corresponding point $y-cx$ as the y coordinate is taken, in the 2) $cx+a$ was used, I don't get the logic

Comment: Suppose you want to get the value at the point $(x,y)$. The function $u(x,y)$ is constant along the line $y=cx+a$. So you draw a line $y=cx+a$ passing the point $(x,y)$. Then, $y=cx+a$ intersects the $y$-axis at point $(0,a)$. Now, what is $a$? It is $cx-y$. You know the value on the boundary, ie $u(0,a)=\sin(a)$. So, $u(x,y)=u(0,a)=\sin(y-cx)$. Note that for different point (x,y), we may have different $a$. It is the intersection of the line $y=cx+a$ with the y-axis.

Comment: ok, understand. Second question to that is if it is correct to think of a solution to type 1) equation (RHS=0) as of some kind of surface which is "flat" (I mean the surface stays at a the level) not sloped in relation to the plane x,y  as opposed to solution of 2) where the RHS=1  so the surface gets sloped in relation to plane x,y. Can this be analysed in that way?

Comment: Actually, this method is called Characteristic Method. The idea of the method is to assume that the function may have some special properties along some characteristic lines (in this case, they are y=cx+a). So, suppose we have values along these lines. when we want to get the value at $(x,y)$, we trace the value at $(x,y)$ along the characteristic line to the boundary point. It is very intuitive. Things will be more difficult if the RHS becomes non-linear. For example, $u_t+cu_x=u^2$. In this case, your explanation is not enough.